# Group by two column and use the distinct values as column name in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, group-by

Basically i need the distinct values from a column to be as column name via Query

Example is below

```
  id status  userId  date
  ------------------------
  1   p      u12  01/01/2014
  2   p      u13  01/01/2014
  3   a      u14  01/01/2014
  4   hd     u15  01/01/2014
  5   a      u16  01/01/2014
  6   p      u12  01/02/2014
  7   a      u13  01/02/2014
  8   p      u14  01/02/2014
```

output

```
 date        p  a  hd
 ------------------------
 01/01/2014  2  2   1
 02/01/2014  2  1   0
```

The status 'p','a','hd' are used as column name and it is grouped by date

Comment: your question is not clear to understand. please specify what is your problem? where did you stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.date, SUM(a.status='p') AS p, SUM(a.status='a') AS a, 
       SUM(a.status='hd') AS hd
FROM tableA a
GROUP BY a.date
```

Check this [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7cbb5/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
|                           DATE | P | A | HD |
|--------------------------------|---|---|----|
| January, 01 2014 00:00:00+0000 | 2 | 2 |  1 |
| January, 02 2014 00:00:00+0000 | 2 | 1 |  0 |
```

Comment: it should be count not sum?

Comment: @DanielRobertus It will count the records. Inner condition will return 1 or 0. So I had used sum instead of count

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, but it forces you to know all possible statuses (result field names) -

```
SELECT
  date,
  COUNT(IF(status = 'p', status, NULL)) AS p,
  COUNT(IF(status = 'a', status, NULL)) AS a,
  COUNT(IF(status = 'hd', status, NULL)) AS hd
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  date;
```

You also can try to automate this logic, have a look at this link - [Dynamic pivot tables (transform rows to columns)](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html).

Answer (score 0):

This SQL is tested

```
    select p.date1,P.p,A.a,case when HD.hd is null then 0 else HD.hd end hd from (select COUNT(status1) p,date1 from tbl1 where status1 ='p' 
group by date1) as P LEFT JOIN (select COUNT(status1) a,date1 from tbl1 where status1 ='a' 
group by date1) as A on P.date1 = A.date1 LEFT JOIN (select COUNT(status1) hd,date1 from tbl1 where status1 ='hd' 
group by date1) as HD on A.date1 = HD.date1
```

just change table name or column name as you wish.